# Listview dentro de Listview ou Repeat dentro de Repeat?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Preciso exibir alguns produtos divididos por categoria, as categorias sao criadas pelo usuario e ambos vem do banco de dados TB_CATEGORIA, TB_PRODUTOS, tem como fazer com `Listview, Repeat`?
Por exemplo:

> Especiais
>
> Produto 1
>   Produto 2
>
> Livros
>
> Livro 1 
>   Livro 2
>
> Antigos
>
> Produto1 Produto2

Comment: É possível fazer os famigerados "Nested Repeaters" ou "Nested ListViews" da vida sim, e isso provavelmente vai resolver seu problema, mas vou confessar que colocar um repeater dentro do outro me deu uma baita dor de cabeça por conta de alguns detalhes infelizes da implementação deles. basta escrever "nested repeater" no google e você verá e enxurrada de perguntas relacionadas a isso (meu evento não dispara, meus dados nao carregam, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Aspx:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptCategorias" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCategoria" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Nome") %>'></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptProdutos" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblProduto" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Nome") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <br />
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</form>
```

Aspx.cs:

```
public partial class _default : Page
{

    private DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ds.TB_CATEGORIA.AddTB_CATEGORIARow(1, "Especiais");
        ds.TB_PRODUTOS.AddTB_PRODUTOSRow(1, ds.TB_CATEGORIA.FindById(1), "Produto 1");
        ds.TB_PRODUTOS.AddTB_PRODUTOSRow(2, ds.TB_CATEGORIA.FindById(1), "Produto 2");

        ds.TB_CATEGORIA.AddTB_CATEGORIARow(2, "Livros");
        ds.TB_PRODUTOS.AddTB_PRODUTOSRow(3, ds.TB_CATEGORIA.FindById(2), "Livro 1");
        ds.TB_PRODUTOS.AddTB_PRODUTOSRow(4, ds.TB_CATEGORIA.FindById(2), "Livro 2");

        ds.TB_CATEGORIA.AddTB_CATEGORIARow(3, "Antigos");
        ds.TB_PRODUTOS.AddTB_PRODUTOSRow(5, ds.TB_CATEGORIA.FindById(3), "Antigos 1");
        ds.TB_PRODUTOS.AddTB_PRODUTOSRow(6, ds.TB_CATEGORIA.FindById(3), "Antigos 2");

        rptCategorias.DataSource = ds;
        rptCategorias.DataMember = "TB_CATEGORIA";
        rptCategorias.ItemDataBound += rptCategorias_ItemDataBound;
        rptCategorias.DataBind();
    }

    protected void rptCategorias_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            var rptProdutos = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptProdutos");
            var row = ((DataRowView) e.Item.DataItem).Row;

            rptProdutos.DataSource = row.GetChildRows(ds.Relations["TB_CATEGORIA_TB_PRODUTOS"]);
            rptProdutos.DataBind();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: E se o segundo Repeater tiver ItemCommand, ItemCreated?

Answer (score 0):

No aspx, inclua dentro de ItemTemplate

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnEdit" CommandName="Edit" 
CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Id") %>' Text="Add"></asp:LinkButton>
```

No codebehind, inclua no evento rptCategorias_ItemDataBound

```
rptProdutos.ItemCommand += rptProdutos_ItemCommand;
```

Crie o evento

```
private void rptProdutos_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "Edit":
            // Your code
            break;
    }
}
```